# I2C Device not found using ESP32 based board (FiPy)

Tags: i2c, communication, esp32

I am trying to read off of a sound level meter which is connected to my [ADC](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Gravity__I2C_ADS1115_16-Bit_ADC_Module_Arduino_%26_Raspberry_Pi_Compatible__SKU__DFR0553#target_5) using a FiPy , as the MCU (see datahseet [here](https://docs.pycom.io/gitbook/assets/specsheets/Pycom_002_Specsheets_FiPy_v2.pdf)). The ADC transmits the data using I2C protocol. The plan is to eventually send SMS texts, based on the sound level.

My problem is the following; When I connect the ADC to my FiPy, the master cannot find the slave/ADC. I have tried attaching a 4.7K resistor between SDA or SCL and VCC, but this did not help.

Here is my block diagram (without the pull-ups, all parts are connected to a common GND on the Arduino):
[image]

Please note, that it is possible to define the SDA and SCL pins through software. The default pins are P9 and P10, and I get the same result using those default pins as I do using the software-designated ones.

Here is the code I used (MicroPython/Python in Atom IDE):

```
import pycom
import time
import machine
from machine import Pin
from machine import I2C
# configure the I2C bus
i2c = I2C(2, I2C.MASTER, baudrate=100000)
print(i2c.scan()) # returns list of slave addresses
read = i2c.readfrom(0x48, 2)
print(read)
```

And here is my error reading:

```
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
OSError: I2C bus error
```

Comment: That's not a schematic. It's a block/wiring diagram. Have you debugged or looked at manual what the error means?

Comment: The fipy uses 3.3V logic methinks, so using a 5 V adc is not suggested. There’s no gnd connection between the fipy and adc.

Comment: @Justme This is a standard MicroPython operation, I cannot find anything in the manual/API guide (https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.I2C.html). But looking through the internet, I found several forum posts that said it was of the I2C master sending a start condition to the slave and not recieving an ack back, which in this context makes sense.

Comment: @Kartman Sorry, that might not've been evidnt from the diagram, but they're using a common GND on the Arduino. I will edit the post. Your comment about 5 V ADC with a 3.3 V logic does seem to make a lot of sense, but I believe that on the ADC's website it says the interface level is High: 3.3V, LOW: 0V. Shouldn't this put the ADC in the range of the ESP32's logic?

Comment: I missed the link to the ‘adc’ you referred to. Nevertheless, your diagram is incomplete and misleading. Don’t underestimate the complexity of what you’re dealing with -  there’s many things that need to be correct otherwise it won’t work as you expect. Length of wire, the exact layout of the wiring etc all can play a part.

Comment: the title of your post does not match the rest of the post